# Unwanted general icon under specified file type icon after installing a WinForm app

Tags: winforms, installation, icons, setup-project, file-type

I'm developing a WinForm app which needs to set the icon for file types specified in Setup project.
My OS is Win7 x64. Visual Studio 2017 Community and .Net Framework 4.6 are used. Icon has transparent pixels and is 128x128.

The problem is, after installation, icons are shown above another icon:

[image]

I just want files to have the exact icon I set:

[image]

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) has the same problem.

**Edit.** I've already tested the following workarounds:

- Resize the icon to 256x256.
- Delete `IconCache.db` from `AppData\Local` folder and restart `explorer.exe`, which is recommended for broken-icons situation (all or some of files and shortcuts have a general icon).

Comment: You should provide a multi-format icon, including: 256x256, 192x192, 128x128, 96x96, 64x64, 48x48, 32x32, 24x24,16x16. See [Icon Converter](https://icoconvert.com/), for example. I assume you have defined an association in the registry.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for helping. I created a multi-size icon as you said. But that didn't help. I have `UserChoice` key under `.jpeg`, `.png` and other file types I specified. The value for `ProgId` is my app name.

Comment: Note that in the associated extension, the default value points to the ProgID of the application that performs the registered operations on the file type. In the ProgID section, you can specify an associated Icon. It's no necessarily a resource inside an executable, it can be, well, the path to an icon file.

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure if I understood correctly. If you mean the value for `(Default)` record inside an extension, it's `(value not set)`. I changed its value to the value of `ProgId`. But nothing changed. Please let me know if I misunderstood what you said. I also changed the value of `DefaultIcon` inside the extension key of `HEKY_CLASSES_ROOT`.